# Stripe API to add account to my stripe platform?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Have been browsing all the documentations which stripe provided. There are API options like create customer object, creating charges, making tokens but unable to find stripe api to add a stripe account to platform's connected account. I can do the same via user interfaced dashboard but when comes to api, am circling around documentations without conclusions.

Is it possible to add existing independent stripe account to connected account of a stripe platform account?

Comment: No, you have to use the OAuth connection approach from https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts , since the account holder needs to agree and authorise the connection to your platform, using the OAuth flow.

Comment: However I found that you can send the oauth url manually to your customers so they can create their account directly `https://dashboard.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXX&scope=read_write`. You can find your oauth url in `Settings > Connect settings`, button `Test Oauth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify to make sure we are all talking about the same thing:

- The expressions "platform", "platform account" and "platform Stripe account" refer in the documentation to the highest form of account *you* can create and manage. These accounts are listed on the top left of your dashboard.
- Stripe Connect is a Stripe product that lets you create Stripe accounts for your users (check [Connect Overview](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to learn about the use cases). These accounts are named connected accounts and can be of three kinds: [Standard Stripe account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts), [Express Stripe account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts), [Custom Stripe Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts).

As far as I understand your question you are unable to find the documentation to create a Stripe account for one of your platform's connected accounts. Is that right ? Tell if I am wrong. I doubt that Stripe allows to create Stripe accounts for connected account (I am not even sure it would be useful). The thing you can do is to create a connected account that will be bound to your platform's Stripe account. To do so the first resources to check out are the following:

- [Create a Connected Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart#create-account) section of the Connect Quickstart page from the Stripe documentation
- [Create an account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) from the Stripe API reference

Comment: Thanks louisfishcer. Will be trying out, will wait for more answers and will mark this as best accordingly, if applies.

Comment: Please change the text for the third account type as Custom Stripe Account instead of Connect Stripe Account.

Comment: Good catch @ArulManivannan I meant Custom Stripe Account. I Hope it helped you understand better how things work. If you have any question just comment this answer.